# using "after" + Past Simple + Present Perfect

Tags: syntax, tense-agreement

Is it okay to use "after" with Past Simple in the subordinate clause and then Present Perfect in the main clause?

For example:

> **After** Marry **married** John, Jack **has been** very reticent about his personal plans.
>
> **After** the revolution **took** place, the neighboring states **have warned** their citizenry against trying similar developments.
>
> **After** the merger **happened**, the new incorporation **has steadily increased** its daily output.
>
> **After** some factories **were** shut down, environmentalist **have kept** repeating again and again that this was their merit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tenses don't work correctly in those expressions. These tenses would work:
After Mary married John, Jack was...
After the revolution took place, the states warned...
After the merger happened, the new corporation steadily increased...
After factories were shut down, environmentalists kept repeating...

If you want to use present perfect tense in the main clause, you need a preposition in the first, subordinate clause that indicates a time continuing into the present, like **since**  instead of **after**.

Comment: So, in short, "after" doesn't go along with Present Perfect, right?

Comment: Yes. I misspoke in my answer about "continuous", which I will correct.